# Applying CSS opacity to dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu, opacity

I have the following jsfiddle setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/jMrsC/1/

I have a dropdown menu on the page when move to Folder 2 > Folder 2.1 the second level submenu  opens up, if you carefully look at the opacity (this is quite tricky to see you may need a good monitor to see the difference) of the second submenu and first submenu there is a difference. In the css I have the following code, which applies the opacity:

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
  display: list-item;
  float: none;
  background: #111;
  opacity: 0.92;
}
```

to me it looks like the opacity has been applied twice to the second submenu and making it  slightly more transparent than the first submenu.

Please can anyone help, I want the first level submenu and second level submenu to have the same opacity.

Thanks

------------------------update---------------------

Sorry I probably wasn't clear before, I would like to apply a consistent opacity to all level submenus and not just remove it.

Thanks

Comment: i m check to this but there are no problum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that opacity is applied to an element's children also. So each time you're creating a sub-menu, its getting 0.92 of the parent's opacity each time.

As spiel suggested, simply removing the opacity from that line may work in your case.

If however, you wanted to target the sub-menus starting at the 2nd level, and keep it consistent from there on, try this:

Remove the opacity from the current class as spiel suggested

First:

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
display: list-item;
float: none;
background: #111;
#opacity: 0.92; <--remove
}
```

Then (make sure this comes after your code above)

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li {
opacity: 0.50
}
```

==== edit =====

Not sure what the etiquette on this is so I'm just going to make an edit. While what I suggested works, the solution given by VenomVendor below is cleaner and better. Instead of doing `.ddsmoothmenu>ul>li>ul>li` as I previously suggested, use `.ddsmoothmenu ul li` instead.

Comment: thanks, perfect worked great. Thanks for quick response and accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ul li ul li` and update it to `ul li` updated at http://jsfiddle.net/jMrsC/5/

```
/*Sub level menu list items (alters style from Top level List Items)*/
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
 display: list-item;
 float: none;
 background: #111;
 }

.ddsmoothmenu ul li{
 opacity: .5;   /* value changed to see the difference */
 }
 .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
  opacity: 1;  /* this means this class is not required, since default opacity is 1 */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply taking away the opacity in that class

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
  display: list-item;
  float: none;
  background: #111;
  #opacity: 0.92;
}
```

worked just fine in your fiddle.

The sub-menu is reading it as using 0.92 opacity of the level above it.